# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

database.php

```
    function insert($sql){
        mysqli_query($this->objDbConn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_errno($this->objDbConn)){
            die("Failed Query: $sql".$this->objDBConn->error);
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

update.php

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $address= $_POST['address'];
    $mail= $_POST['mail'];
    $user= $_POST['user'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    $sql= "UPDATE Member(Address, Mail, UserName, Password)VALUES
        ('$address', '$mail', '$user', '$password')";

    $objdatabase->insert($sql);
    echo "Update successful";
    echo "<META http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL='>";
}
```

that show on the url:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

and

Notice: Undefined property: database::$objDBConn

Comment: and now i have Failed Query: UPDATE Member showing my url so i wonder is it cant connect to the database?

Comment: Related: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo, property name is case sensitive, `$this->objDBConn` should be `$this->objDbConn`.

Comment: Aaah ... and i was wondering what is different about your code.